# BGinfo on logon screen (Windows 7, Non-Administrator)

Tags: windows-7, permissions, login

In Windows 7, it's not that easy to show information on the logon screen with BGinfo. I got it working by converting the BMP file (that BGinfo creates) to a JPG file (with BMP2JPG.exe), and placing it in the following folder

> C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\backgroundDefault.jpg

This works perfectly for Administrators, but a normal user doesn't have the permission to write in that folder. So when a normal users logs on, the desktop is updated, but the logon screen isn't (until an Administrator logs on).

Is there a way to get this working for non-admins? I Think I've opened every Google page I could find, but nothing has come up.

Thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried to set write permission for the folder to `users` group?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by settings permissions to the folder with PowerShell.

```
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit -bor [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
$objType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 
$Folder = "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds"
$acl = Get-Acl $Folder
$permission = "Everyone","Modify", $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
Set-Acl $Folder $acl
```